# Looking for standard pom.xml format to execute ONLY TEST goal as "mvn surefire:test" without dependent goals 'clean, compile'

Tags: maven, maven-plugin, maven-surefire-plugin

My requirement is to execute only "mvn test" command without its dependent goals and found answer as "mvn surefire:test" will do it. But when I execute using this command, I see message as 'No Test to run'.

I suspect, pom.xml need some changes to execute 'mvn surefire:test' command. Kindly share pom.xml format to be used here.

Comment: If you do not compile your tests first, you cannot run them.

Comment: Apart from what JF Meier wrote..Why do you like to do that? Maven has a life cycle for a good reason..you do `mvn test` to compile and run your tests..? So I don't understand your requirement?

Comment: I am executing cucumber test scenarios in parallel using multiple batch files executing different feature files. I have a batch file to compile code & I execute that at the beginning. So, execution batch file just need to execute it from the compiled source. If each of my batch file keep executing clean, compile, I end up getting 'NoClassDefFoundError'.